# Jquery Index function with selector string

Tags: jquery

As I know from Jquery learning, function index of jquery can be used:

- `.index()` // no arguments
- `.index(domObject)` // argument is a dom object
- `.index(JqueryObject)` // argument is a Jquery object
- `.index("selectorString")` // argument is a selector string

I'm testing index function with argument is a selector string.

html -> body:

```
<div class="name" id="id1">
  <h2>Z</h2>
  <h2>X</h2>
</div>
<div class="name" id="id2">
  <h2>A</h2>
  <h2>B</h2>
</div>
```

Jquery scripts:

```
var index1 = $('.name').index("#id1");
var index2 = $('.name').index("#id2");
alert(index1);
alert(index2);
```

The results are: 0 for index1 (correct) and -1 for index2 (not correct).

So, The question is: Why I can not get the correct index value of div#id2?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GhPxD/60/

Comment: swap it `$("#id2").index('.name');`, that gets the index of `#id2` in the `.name` collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no bug here, the API is just... strange. [Here's the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/) :

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.
>
> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an
>   integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery
>   object relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the
>   element is not found, .index() will return -1.

What you want is thus

```
$('#id2').index(".name");
```

Having this function behave in so different ways is very confusing IMO.

Comment: Basically, you are correct. 
$('#id2').index(".name"); and
$('#id1').index(".name");
return the correct result and it seems that is the way of using index function with selector string argument. 
But one more thing can you explain:
why  $('.name').index("#id1"); return the correct index? Is it accidentally correct?

Comment: The first .name element is #id1. So the index of the first .name element in the set #id1 is 0. Yes, that's accidentally correct. I'm not sure many developers can correctly use the index function with arguments at first try...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass jquery object in index method to make this work:

```
var index = $('.name').index($("#id2"));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcxgvpev/)**

Comment: It appears the documentation is wrong as this does indeed work, yet the docs state a string selector can be provided. It could also be a bug in jQuery itself.

Comment: What you did is using the 3nd method I mention above:
.index(JqueryObject) // argument is a Jquery object

Answer (score -1):

```
statement 1 :  var index1 = $('.name').index("#id1");
statement 2 :  var index2 = $('.name').index("#id2");
```

***statement 1***
   1.As you know when you use any selector in jquery it return first matching element 
   2. now you try to find index of `index("#id1")`  so it found sucessfully at index 0 so it `return 0`

***statement 2***
   1.As you know when you use any selector in jquery it return first matching element 
   2. now you try to find index of `index("#id2")`  so it unable to found any child element with `#id2` so it `reurn -1`

Comment: Sorry, I dont think you are correct at this statement "when you use any selector in jquery it return first matching element".  $('.name') return a Jquery object with 2 doms inside it (div#id1 and div#id2)